# working to Hex data using C++

Tags: c++, hex, hex-editors

need to help me for working hex string using c++

1. how to open file binary data hex line by line c++
2. how to split line using delimiter like 0x3D c++
3. how to store all lines in vector map except the line founded of search.

ex.
syntax file binary

```
32 32 32 32 32 32 30 3D 32 30 31 31 31 30 31 30 

32 32 32 32 32 32 31 3D 32 30 31 31 31 30 31 30 

32 32 32 32 32 32 32 3D 32 30 31 31 31 30 31 30

32 32 32 32 32 32 33 3D 32 30 31 31 31 30 31 30
```

delimiter = 3D

search = `0x32 0x32 0x32 0x32 0x32 0x32 0x32`

last step how to output founded from search like `0x32 0x30 0x31 0x31 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30`
store char*

please help me

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/flags/

Comment: If your binary file has \n characters that you interpret as end of line, then the file is not binary, but text file.

Comment: hi JoshD, text file containing like above hex data

Comment: Also does not contain spaces between text

Comment: Does the file contain end-of-line characters? Maybe \n?

Answer (score 0):

You are not being too clear.

I will assume that you have a file with those characters (btw, TEXT file, not binary), and you want to read it line by line, then split eache line by "3D" and then store each part in a char*.

First of, read about opening file for reading and how to read line by line, you will found it in any tutorial.

Second, use strtoken() to 'split' the line by "3D". Remember that at this point, it's only text, forget about hex.

Later that you can use scanf() to read each part as hex and store them into char*, then you can compare this and store what you want.

If the file is binary, then you will need to look for getc() function or gets(), but the idea is the same. In the second step, if you need to split it by 0x3d hex value, just do it.